# What to do about NAA posts that are still NAA after being edited in review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, flags, not-an-answer

Recently, I flagged an answer as Not An Answer, because it contained information that should actually be edited into the question itself (code to clarify the question).

However, one of the reviewers edited the answer instead of recommending to delete it. This caused the flag to be marked as helpful and the post being removed from the Low Quality Posts queue.

In this case, the post was still NAA after the reviewer edited it. What is the right approach to handle this situation? I can't re-flag it as Not An Answer since the option is greyed out.

Comment: FWIW a lot of people are unaware that editing inside of the LQP queue actually completes the review. Well that has been my experience when noticing similar things elsewhere.

Comment: Downvote the answer and hope someone else flags it, or the OP eventually gets peer pressured into deleting the non-answer. And then move on to the hundreds of other answers that require attention.

Comment: @Gimby I'll move on. It's just that I'm encountering this situation occasionally, and having a proper solution will help when one of those other hundreds of answers that require attention fall into the same category as in this case. I'll start with downvoting when it happens again, though I'm having doubts if this will help in less-popular tags since I'll probably the only downvoter. But you can't fix everything I guess.

Comment: Will it let you flag it as VLQ?

Comment: @RobertColumbia Yes, I can flag it as anything else, just not as an NAA because I already did that (even though the answer changed due to the edit).

Comment: no @psubsee2003 there is that difference, I tested that and you can test that too. Do the edit outside of the queue and after that you can see how post stays under review

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Flag it as VLQ. This should either put it back into the LQP review queue or send it to a moderator who can delete it.

If this doesn't work, ask in chat for someone else to flag it as NAA. As @rene mentioned, you can make a `reflag-pls` request in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room for that.

If you can't find anyone in chat to flag it, flag it for special moderator attention (custom flag), explaining that it is not an answer but that the system won't allow you to flag it as such.

Comment: The SOCVR room is open for reflag-pls requests. The scenario the OP describes is mentioned in our FAQ [here](https://socvr.org/faq#can-i-request-people-to-vote-or-flag-on-posts-i-find)

Comment: since this involves LQ review abuse I personally prefer to immediately flag for mod attention, pointing both to NAA and review problem. Typically text of my custom _follow-up_ flag looks like this: "this is a question edit dumped into the answer box. Using custom flag because my prior NAA, along with LQ review were broken by a senseless edit: <link to abused LQ review>"