# Can I raise the same flag after a period of time?

Tags: support, flags

Some flags may be handled by the community, some flags may be handled by a moderator, some flags may age away. If I believe that the outcome of a flag wasn't ideal, **can I raise the same non-custom flag after a period of time?**

---

I'm raising this question because this is something that is possible with close votes: once a close-review is *invalidated*, then attempting to close-vote again will give us such opportunity roughly 20 days later. For instance, one could see:

> You have already voted to close this question, but you may vote again on Sep 17 at 3:02

---

When attempting to re-flag, we do not see such time indication:
[image]

Comment: you seem to be confusing voting to close and flagging

Comment: Also probably related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332953/allow-reflagging-of-posts-marked-helpful since the image shows upvoted and accepted post

Comment: that's a baaaad answer... I wouldn't have resisted to post the link :) I found it anyway... and flagged

Answer (score 14):

No, you can't raise the same flag on a post even after an arbitrary period of time. This is [clarified by Brad Larson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332955/1033581):

> There are problems with allowing someone to continually re-flag the same post with the same flag. We see this with comment flags, where people will regularly flag and re-flag the same innocuous comment in order to have it destroyed.

Comment: or they might come back to it after a while and re-flag without remembering.

Comment: Sadly, in some cases it could be annoying though. In multiple cases I've seen an NAA flag being cleared due to an incorrect edit in the review queue. Luckily there's always SOCVR and the `reflag-pls` request (as rene mentioned in [my related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369137/what-to-do-about-naa-posts-that-are-still-naa-after-being-edited-in-review)).

Answer (score 2):

It is mechanically possible to raise the same flag on a post a second time if the original flag aged away without ever being handled.

As far as I can tell, it is also allowed by policy to reflag in this scenario, especially if editing won't fix the issue. The answers to [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332953/2460971) Coeur linked talk about the problems with trying to overturn a decision, but in this case no decision was ever reached.

Comment: How long to wait for a flag to age away?

Comment: @Cœur Based on a quick check of my own flag history, it looks like it takes a couple weeks for a flag to be marked as aged away and about a month for reflagging to become possible.